# Changing an instance variable within dynamic method (dynamic resource using ActiveResource)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeresource, dynamic-dispatch

I am using dynamic dispatch to define several class methods in a class that inherits from ActiveResource.

```
class Invoice < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = 'http://localhost:8080/'

  def self.define(method)
    define_singleton_method(method) do |params = {}|
      site = self.site
      self.site = "#{self.site}/Invoice/#{method.to_s.camelize(:lower)}"

      puts "self.site -> #{self.site}"  
      results = Invoice.all(params: params)

      self.site = site
      puts "changing self.site back to #{site}"     

      return results
    end
  end

  define :get_details
  define :put_approval
  define :get_attachment
  define :get_pending_notifications
end
```

This works great for the first call, whatever it is (Invoice.get_details, Invoice.get_pending_notifications...), but always fails on the second call.

I would like to understand why this is happening and what I can do to get it fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Researching this further, I have found that `self.site` is not actually changing when I ask it to.  It tells me it is changing in the logs, but it lies!  `self.site` does not change from its initial set state in the first method called.  I have a theory as to why this is not working and a workaround to get it working.

**First, my theory:**

When any one of the class methods defined is called, `site` is set.  Since `site` is outside of the scope of the class method being called, once it is set initially, it cannot be changed thereafter.

An example:

```
Invoice.get_details
```

`Invoice.site` is initially set to "localhost:8080/Invoice/getDetails"

```
Invoice.get_pending_notifications
```

`Invoice.site` cannot be changed because it is already defined as "localhost:8080/Invoice/getDetails"

The above is just a working theory.

**How I got this working:**

Remove all references to `self.site` except for the initial set `self.site = "localhost:8080"` and instead use a url string.  (Under the section "Finding resources from custom paths" at  http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596521424/activeresource_id59243.html )

```
class Invoice < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "localhost:8080"
  def self.define(method)
    define_singleton_method(method) do |params = {}|
      url = "#{self.site}/Invoice/#{method.to_s.camelize(:lower)}"

      # results = Invoice.all(params: params) <- Change this call to below
      results = Invoice.find(:all, from: url, params: params) 

      return results
    end
  end

  define :get_details
  define :put_approval
  define :get_attachment
  define :get_pending_notifications
end
```

Using the code above, I can call any of the methods defined, each pointing to a different url, without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the site is not getting reset properly. Try this, it works under ruby console:

```
class Invoice < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = 'http://localhost:8080/'

  def self.define(method)
    define_singleton_method(method) do |params = {}|
      site = self.site
      begin
        self.site = "#{self.site}/Invoice/#{method.to_s.camelize(:lower)}"
        Invoice.all(params: params)
      ensure
        # this code will always be run, even if there is an exception above
        # and it won't affect the original value returned above
        self.site = site
      end
    end
  end

  define :get_details
  define :put_approval
  define :get_attachment
  define :get_pending_notifications
end
```

Comment: I just tried what you have and it does not seem to be working for me.  I get either ActiveResource::ForbiddenAccess or ActiveResource::ServerError on the second call depending on which method I call first.